# Comparing hashed passwords, Is it better to compare on the server or on the database using SQL?

Tags: hash, passwords

I am building a system for authentication, and obviously to do so I will need to compare submitted passwords to hashed stored passwords in the database.
As far as I understand, I can either have the web service use SQL to get the hashed password value and salt, and evaluate on the server. Alternatively, I believe I could use SQL to do the comparison using the database, if I first use the server to extract the salt value, hash the salted password and send it to the database to evaluate. In other words:

Method One:

1. Receive username and password from the user.
2. Use SQL to extract the user's salt value and hashed password.
3. Use the salt and the provided password to compute a hashed password.
4. Evaluate whether to grant access by comparing the stored password with the newly hashed password.

Method Two:

1. Receive username and password from the user.
2. Use SQL to extract only the salt value from the database.
3. Use the salt and provided password to compute a hashed password.
4. Use an SQL query to compare the stored password with the newly hashed password.
5. SQL query returns whether the hashed passwords match.
6. Grant access to user based on results of SQL query.

Which would be the better practice?

Comment: "if I first use the server to extract the salt value, hash the salted password and send it to the database to evaluate." that will be vulnerable to timing attacks.

Comment: @PeeHaa In theory, could both methods not be vulnerable? Both methods could have a malicious agent intercepting the salt as it is necessary to use the salt to compute a salted version of the password with the server.

Comment: So what you're saying is that there is no difference either way since neither method has any inherent benefits?

Comment: No that is not what I said. Read my first comment again. Method two is vulnerable to timing attacks